# How to mock rabbitmq to test the standalone Spring cloud data flow processor?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a SCDF processor using PolledProcessor to poll from the input rabbitmq every second. Is there a way to mock the input rabbitmq so that I can verify the polling behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mock RabbitMQ. Use the `TestChannelBinder` from SpringCloudStream and register a `MessageSource<byte[]>` to simulate content received from a `PollableSource`. You need to include the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As an example, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/PollableConsumerTests.java